# How to set up wireless printer HP m201 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: printing, libreoffice, hp, 22.04

My OS is Ubuntu 22.04 and the printer is a wireless printer HP laserjet pro m201dw

Checking the setting of Ubuntu , it seems that the printer is identified and that it is "ready"
[image]

I tried to print using LibreOffice Writer. The result is that Libreoffice keeps not responding. With finally the following message:
[image]

I tried to print a Google Doc. Firefox web browser. No result.

I understood that a generic HP driver is already on Ubuntu 22.04

What should I do?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Access the CUPS (Common Unix Printing Sysyem) GUI by pointing your browser  to `http://localhost:631`.

You can detect, add, and manage printers from the `Admin` tab, and deal with individual printers from the `Printers` tab.

From the command line,

```
lpstat -t
```

will show the total state of the printing system.

Comment: Be careful with exact, copy and paste answers on AU, usually there will be some specific changes needed to *directly address* each question...